# django social auth , create user model with email as primary key

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-socialauth

I am trying to integrate django social auth for my website which will have Facebook and Google login. I am trying to customize the user model to make email as primary key.
Any advice ?
I tried creating a UserModel also but ended up with errors.
i tried creating a pipeline enter code here

```
from social_auth.backends.pipeline.user import create_user
def custom_create_user(request, *args, **kwargs):
      print kwargs
      return create_user(request, args, kwargs)
```

My aim is to have a site with Facebook And Google - oauth2 login with email as primary key !

Answer (score 0):

Well I am doing facebook login for my ios app. What I am doing is

1. Login to facebook from my app and get the facebook access token
2. Send the facebook email and access token to the django backend
3. Then what I do is, instead of using the django default authenticate method which takes the username and password to authenticate a user, I overwrite my own authenticate method. Doing this is really easy just read [Django Custom Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/)
4. In my custom authentication class I verify the email-token pair sent from the front using [fb sdk for python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fb/0.3.0) and that is it. After than I can login the user using the django in built login